Problem involving 3 circumferences
I am trying to prove the statement $OQ+QP=2OP$ where the letters, the draw and my attempt is in the following image. Now, as you can see I am not on the right track because after substituting I do not get the final identity. Am I doing something wrong?


My second attempt is with coordinates, if I do get something I will post something

Here's a suggested approach, calculate $m/R$ (that's the main work - you can determine this ratio by working backwards from the following steps) and hence $\tan \angle QOX = m/(R-m)$, and use tan addition/subtraction formula to show that $ \tan POQ = 3/4$. So we have a 3-4-5 triangle, and the sum of the 2 sides is twice of the 4-base.

HINT.-Let angle $\angle{POQ}=\alpha$. By law of cosinus you have a quadratic equation in $OP$ so you get $$2OP=OQ\cos(\alpha)\pm\sqrt{Q^2\cos^2\alpha-OQ^2+PQ^2}$$ ¿Can you follow and finish?

@Piquito I am trying about this: $PQ^2=OQ^2-OP^2$ and $OQ=\frac{OP}{\cos(\alpha)}$ and so the square root goes to 0? I think I am doing something wrong


Geometric solution: In figure F is the reflection of O over QP. Draw acircle on O with radius $OF=2OP$, it intersect the extension of OQ at H. Draw a circle on Q and tangent to previous circle that means it pass point H because OH passe Q. This circle intersect PQ at K. Draw a tangent from F on this circle to meet it at point D. Since $QP\bot FP$  FP must also be a tanget from F and $FD=FP$. Also $QK=QH$ then K must be coincident on P, that is $OH=OK=OP$ and we have:
$OQ+QH=OQ+QP=OH=OF=2OP$

Thanks for the geometric solution, really appreciate it!

@MiguelCG, You are welcome.
